# Problems loading csv data with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I've been trying to implement [this](https://codepen.io/GrantCuster/pen/QQXRqj) 2D visualization for my own project, and I'm having problems loading in CSV data instead of randomly generating points. My code is almost identical to the link above, except for this:

```
<script>
    let data_points = [];
    d3.csv("mnist2D.csv", function (d) {
        d.forEach(function (d,i) {
            data_points[i] = {
                x: +d.x,
                y: +d.y,
                name: 'Knowledge Element ' + i,
                group: +d.label,
                radius: +d.radius,
                frequency: +d.frequency
            };
        })

    ...remainder of the script

    //d3.csv end
    })
</script>
```

The error I get back in the browser console is

```
Uncaught TypeError: o.beforesend is undefined
    send 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1'
    n 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1'
    Cn 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1'
    e 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:3'
    <anonymous> 'https://...../test2d:22' //Line of the d3.csv call
```

This code works perfectly fine with a 3D version of this that doesn't use d3-zoom and tooltips, but breaks in this one. I'm assuming it has to do with d3.csv being asynchronous, but I'm not an experienced JS developer and have no idea how to debug such an issue. Would using d3.js v5 solve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're using d3v3 and mention your code works without zoom. The example link implements a zoom using d3 v4/5, this won't work in d3v3 (eg: d3.zoom in v4/5 is d3.behavior.zoom in v3). Have you accounted for v3 differences in adapting the example code?

Comment: True, I switched to v5 and it worked! posting the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem funnily enough. Switched to d3 v5 and had no issues loading the data.

```
<script>
    // Load in data (asynchronously)
    d3.csv("mnist2D.csv", function (data) {
        return {
            x: +data.x*50,
            y: +data.y*50,
            name: data.name,
            label: +data.label,
            radius: +data.radius,
            frequency: +data.frequency
        };
    }).then(function(data_points) {

    ...remainder of the script

    //d3.csv end
    })
</script>
```